# Searching for a fix for my discord bot's 8ball command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

If I simply use ?8ball, the command works just fine. I can't seem to figure out how to make the bot reply if I add my question to the command e.g. ?8ball Should I stay at home? or ?8ball Yes or no?

How do I make my bot react to the 8ball command if there's a user's question in it? I bet it is pretty simple but I don't know much about coding unfortunately.

Thanks for helping.

This is the code. It works for ?8ball but not if I add a question.

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === '?8ball') {
     msg.reply(eightball[Math.floor(Math.random() * eightball.length)]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your if statement is explicitly looking for

> ?8ball

If you want it to respond to any request that [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) '?8ball' you could instead use:

```
client.on('message', msg => {
    if( msg.content.includes('?8ball') ) {
        msg.reply(eightball[Math.floor(Math.random() * eightball.length)]);
    }
}
```

To note, this will not work to determine the question they are asking, just that it includes a predefined string (Worse is that it doesn't check if the string is at the front of the message or in the middle).  You will have to do additional parsing in order to get the question from the message, such as [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

An example of using String.split() and [Array.shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) with [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to get the content of the message separate from the query:

```
client.on('message', msg => {
    var msgarray = msg.content.split(' ');

    //If the first part of the created array matches your message.
    if( msgarray[0] === '?8ball' ) {

        //Remove first part of array and put it together again.
        msgarray.shift();

        //Put the user query back together without the first part and spaces between the words
        var msgcontent = msgarray.join(' ');

        msg.reply(eightball[Math.floor(Math.random() * eightball.length)]);
    }
});
```

Comment: It says Reference error now, msg is not defined. Any idea on what I could've done wrong? I'm a newb at coding and what I got here already took me forever :/ @RageFoxx

Comment: @roterputzlumpe I've updated it to include the missing part.  I highly recommend continuing to learn.  It might seem hard now but you'll get there if you keep going.  And try to follow the links I have provided in there - They help explain what is going on.

Comment: `msg.content.split(/\s+/g)` is a better option to define arguments. By splitting at spaces, some arguments will contain spaces (or be just spaces) and line breaks. `\s` matches spaces *and* line breaks, and `+` matches any amount in between arguments.

Comment: @slothiful Only problem with that I see is that it won't be reconstructed back into it's original form if you split by line breaks.  Splitting strictly by spaces would allow the line breaks to be preserved.  With multiple arguments you could reference the starting indices similarly to the first index above.  It would be odd to have an argument be a linebreak or a space, but all the same you could successfully compare them with simple space separation.

Comment: You can simply slice `message.content` if you want to preserve the question format.